# java.sql.SqlException : java.lang.OutofHeapMemory Error

Tags: java

I am getting java.sql.SqlException : java.lang.OutofHeapMemory Error.Please suggest me what kind of error this may be?

Comment: You're running out of Heap Memory...

Comment: See this happens when a SqlException and a loop or a recursive function fall in love. They love each other so much they start making little baby objects and eventually the JVM runs out of place to keep the little babies gets pissed offf and goes commando on everything and shuts down!

Comment: A common reason for this is failing to close your SQL resources such as PreparedStatement.close();

Answer (score 2):

You outgrow the allocated memory for your JVM.

There is too many possible reason to answer simply, but as you encounter it in JDBC stack, it may be caused by a request pulling too many data.

Possible immediate remedy is:

1. Limit request result set
2. Increase JVM memory

For long term solution, do a heapdump and analyse it with tools like MAT.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried increasing memory to program?

```
java -Xmx256M
```

But this question is very ambiguous.